# What is the best way to include traits in the model?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have my own user model which requires some permissions. I created `/app/models/Permissions.php` inside which is trait. Now i need to use it in `/app/models/MyUser.php`. How to do this in Laravel style?

Answer (score 3):

I would do that this way.

**1.** Model

```
<?php namespace Models;

// app/models/MyUser.php

class MyUser extends \Eloquent {
    use \Traits\Permissions;
    /* ... */
}
```

**2.** Create Trait itself

```
<?php namespace Traits;

// app/traits/Permissions.php

trait Permissions {
    /* ... */
}
```

**3.** Modify composer.json and add this into `classmap`

```
"app/traits",
```

**4.** In order Laravel could autoload traits you need to dump autoload file and generate new one

```
php artisan dump
```

Comment: dont work, fires `
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException

Trait 'Traits\Permissions' not found
`

Comment: Error related to namespace? Do you understand them?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the example Andreyco.

To complement this helps to add a function to the model itself. For example, this would be entered in the Trait. In step 2

```
public function scopeGetMyFunction($query, Request $request)
{
     //more code....
     $query->get();    
}
```

and so we can use it as part of the Model on the controller.

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $models = \App\Models\User::getMyFunction($request);
        return $models;
    }
```